# Duplicate Settings In Reference DLL

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dll

I have a DLL with several properties and a function that generates runs a SSRS report in the background and saves it to a PDF file.

I have a DataTable with all the reports that need to be generated and where they need to be saved.

I want to make each instance of the DLL run in a separate thread.  I took a stab at it found the 2nd row in the DataTable overrode the first row.

Here is the Class/DLL Code

```
Public Class SSRSFunctions
    Private Shared _Formated_Parameters As String
    Private Shared _Report_Parameters As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Property FORMATED_PARAMETERS() As String
        Get
            Return _Formated_Parameters
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Formated_Parameters = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        _Report_Parameters = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Sub
    Public Function RenderReportToFile() As String

        'RenderReportHere

    End Function
    Public Sub AddParameter(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Value As String)
        If _Report_Parameters.ContainsKey(Name) Then
            _Report_Parameters.Remove(Name)
            _Report_Parameters.Add(Name, Value)
        Else
            _Report_Parameters.Add(Name, Value)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the calling Code

```
Private Sub CheckForNewRequests()
    'Filter DataTable for Reports to Run

    For Each dr As DataRow in DateTable.Rows
        Dim rpt As New SSRSFunctions
        Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartNewThread)            
        rpt.FORMATED_PARAMETERS = (dr("REPORT_PARAMS"))
        t1.Start(rpt)
    Next
End Sub
Private Function StartNewThread(ByVal report As SSRSFunctions) As String
    Return report.RenderReportToFile()
End Function
```

I am trying to figure out why the "Dim rpt As New SSRSFunctions" is not creating a new instance of the DLL and so the second row of the dataTable has a new instance to store it's parameters.

The second row is overriding the first.

Help?

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont make the private properties shared, remove the `Shared` keyword from the declarations.
change

```
Private Shared _Formated_Parameters As String
Private Shared _Report_Parameters As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

to

```
Private _Formated_Parameters As String
Private _Report_Parameters As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

By sharing them you are saying that no matter how many instances of the class is created always use (share) the same instance of the shared internal variable.